# buildroot does not copy C++ headers to sysroot

Tags: buildroot

I started to used buildroot for my project.  The project uses the codesourcery arm 2013.05.

All works fine, I have create bootable kernel image and a proper rootfs.  Adding c based autotools packages is no problem.  The programs created by the packages are on the target and run well.

The problems start when I add a C++ package.  It fails to compile with the error "unsafe usage of /usr/include".  Looking at the output of the configure shows this:

checking string usability... no
checking string presence... no
checking for string... no
checking vector usability... no
checking vector presence... no
checking for vector... no

When I look for the C++ header in the output folder of buildroot (ouput/host) I cannot find any of these C++ headers.

So I suspection buildroot not to installing/cp-ing the C++ headers.

Note: when configuring and building the package manually with the external toolchain - so not using buildroot - everythinh is fine - as the c++ headers are available in the external toolchain.

What I do wrong here ??

Answer (score 1):

Buildroot is definitely copying the C++ headers, and people are building C++ applications every day with Buildroot.

However, if when building your application you get "unsafe usage of /usr/include", then it means that the Makefile of your application is broken, as it passes -I/usr/include in the CFLAGS, which is really bad when cross-compiling. Fix this, and your C++ header will go away.